# TPM version report AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, tpm

Is it possible to identify the TPM version of active directory machines using powershell?
The following script works, but the computer must be turned on:

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties $Properties
$FormattedComputers = foreach ($_ in $Computers) {
   [Array] $Tpm = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Tpm -namespace root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm -ComputerName $_.Name
   if ($Tpm) {
      $TpmVersion = $Tpm[0].PhysicalPresenceVersionInfo
   } else {
      $TpmVersion = $null
   }
}
```

Do you know if there is any object that I can capture using Get-ADObject and give me that info?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I am aware, it is not possible to get the TPM version from anything other than the computer. In theory, if it were stored in AD, it could be out of date if that computer object was assigned to a new physical machine.

Comment: As aside.. the `$_` automatic variable is not to be used in a `foreach()` loop.

Comment: If you have SCCM in your environment, that can tell you the TPM version, but Active Directory doesn't store that info

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Otter and @ Jonathan for your comments.

Yes, There is no way to get the TPM version for Active directory.